# jupyter notebook's kernel keeps dying when using dearpygui

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dearpygui

1. Just installed dearpygui 1.8.0 module in a proper environment.
2. Then I ran the first step's code from:
   https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/first-steps.html
3. here is the code :

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()
dpg.create_viewport(title='Custom Title', width=600, height=300)

with dpg.window(label="Example Window"):
    dpg.add_text("Hello, world")
    dpg.add_button(label="Save")
    dpg.add_input_text(label="string", default_value="Quick brown fox")
    dpg.add_slider_float(label="float", default_value=0.273, max_value=1)

dpg.setup_dearpygui()
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

4. returns the error :

```
The kernel for Documents ... /DearPyGui/Studies&Tries.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

5. The same code ran directly from my python installation works well.
6. Command:

```
(dpg_py310) amen@ubu:~$ python dpg01.py
```

7. reinstalling dearpygui 1.8.0 gives the same result
8. donwngrading to dearpygui 1.7.3 makes no change
9. no solution found on the net

Need help

Comment: I am unsure why you expect it to work in Jupyter? You specifically say, "The same code ran directly from my python installation works well." You should read more about the purpose [here](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/what-why.html). Specifically, the earlier stuff about how it doesn't use native widgets and is, "a simple way for python developers to create quick and powerful GUIs for scripts." Key is it is for Python script files, and not notebooks, and uses widgets separate from those Jupyter uses. Jupyter is it's own GUI and doesn't play well with another running in it.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/563) the OP says, "the output that Jupyter throws (I know DPG can't run on it)." Which makes me think my questioning your expectation was correct. Some already reported your observation [in the issues at the 
DearPyGui repo](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/1462). Unfortunately, no one chimed in with the technical reason and so I cannot point you at this definitively. [Here](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/1949) does say browser-support is not on the horizon which is where Jupyter generally runs.

Comment: I am facing the same issue - kernel failing with "[error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221225477, Reason: "